# Digital Filter Coefficients using butter

Tags: python, matlab, filtering, signal-processing

so um trying to implement a low pass digital filter that cuts all freuquencies above 5000 hz for a signal from .wav file it's sampling rate = 38000
so i use signal.butter to get the coefficients
  but when adding a frequency of 6000 to my function it does not filter it ,, actually it begin to filter from 15000 hz 
can someone know where is the reason for that

```
    from scipy import signal
    nyq =0.5 *38000
    b, a = signal.butter(5,5000/nyq, btype='low', analog=False, output='ba')

def browse_txt(self):

    filepath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Single File', "C:\Users\Hanna Nabil\Desktop",'*.txt')

    y=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
    x=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    content = [s.strip() for s in content]
    print len(content)
    index = 0

    p=[]
    while index < len(content):
        x[0] = x[1]
        x[1] = x[2]
        x[2] = x[3]
        x[3] = x[4]
        x[4] = x[5]
        x[5] = float(content[index])
        y[0] = y[1]
        y[1] = y[2]
        y[2] = y[3]
        y[3] = y[4]
        y[4] = y[5]
        #x = float(content[index])
        y[5] =0.00405468* x[5] + 0.0202734 * x[4] +0.0405468 * x[3] + 0.0405468 * x[2] +0.0202734* x[1] +  0.00405468 * x[0]
        - (-2.34299118)*y [4]-  2.58241136*y[3] -(-1.5249425)*y[2] -0.47760386 *y[1]- (-0.06233179)*y[0]
        #p0 = float(content[index])
        p.append(y[5])


        index += 1
    self.signal=np.array(p)

    self.time = np.linspace(0, 1, 38000 * 1)

    freq = fftfreq(self.signal.size, 1.0/38000)
    self.xfourier =freq[:int(len(freq) / 2)]

    mag= abs(fft(self.signal))
    self.yfourier = mag[:int(len(mag) / 2)]



    self.drawOn1()
    self.drawOn3()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to implement the filter yourself. If you're using `scipy`, you can use that module's methods to filter your signal for you. Given your signal `x`, do: `scipy.signal.lfilter(b, a, x)` (or `scipy.signal.filtfilt(b, a, x)` or similar).

Comment: i need to do that myself as um using the coefficients in another online processing project

Comment: No problem, you can still get the coefficients from the `b` and `a` values returned from `signal.butter`, right? That's pretty much what you've got in your line computing `y[5]`, I believe. Using the SciPy filtering methods will be faster and less error-prone than rolling your own implementation.

Comment: i get the coefficient but the filtering starts from 15000 if my fc that i put in the butter coefficients is 5000 
Do u have any idea why is that??

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean "filtering starts from 15000"?